# Soundcloud Player Modification

Tags: javascript, php, html, soundcloud

I am building a website for a friend and he wants the Soundcloud player embedded with an image above it that changes each time a different song plays. Each track will have its own image that will show as the track is played in the Soundcloud player.

The image that is assigned to each track on Soundcloud does show in the embedded player, but only at a size of 150x150. I would like to disable this image and have a much larger image displayed above the player.

Does anybody know if this is possible and how I would go about doing such a thing. My knowledge of HTML and CSS is strong. However, other languages such as Javascript and PHP are fairly new to me, so please excuse any silly questions.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The soundcloud widget has an `show_artwork` option. You could set this to false to hide the artwork in the player. Then you could retrieve the artwork in a larger format using the api (check for the `artwork_url` property of the track).